# Defining context for yup object results in empty object

Tags: typescript, yup

Defining an object with a set context to be used during validation causes the object type to collapse to `{}`:

```
import { object, string, number, AnyObject } from 'yup';

interface Context extends AnyObject {
  availableProducts: string[];
}

const mySchema = object<Context>({
    productName: string().required(),
    amount: number().min(0),
  })
  .test('some-fancy-test', ({ productName }, { options: { context } }) => {
    if (!context) throw new Error('No context');

    // Error: Property 'productName' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
    const { availableProducts } = context;

    return availableProducts.includes(productName);
  });

mySchema.validateSync(
  { productName: 'apple', amount: 1 },
  { context: { availableProducts: ['apple', 'banana'] } }
);
```

How do I define the context without specifying the entire object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define the object first and then use `.shape()` for the actual object content as it overrides the `{}` shape:

```
import { object, string, number, AnyObject } from 'yup';

interface Context extends AnyObject {
  availableProducts: string[];
}

const mySchema = object<Context>()
  .shape({
    productName: string().required(),
    amount: number().min(0),
  })
  .test('some-fancy-test', ({ productName }, { options: { context } }) => {
    if (!context) throw new Error('No context');

    const { availableProducts } = context;

    return availableProducts.includes(productName);
  });

mySchema.validateSync(
  { productName: 'apple', amount: 1 },
  { context: { availableProducts: ['apple', 'banana'] } }
);
```